# expand a rational function in a power series

Tags: power-series, rational-functions

$$\frac{4-x}{(2-x)(1-x)^2}$$
Expand in ascending powers of x, stating when the expansion is valid; also write down the coefficient of $x^n $

Comment: Do you know about partial fractions?

Comment: You could use partial fractions first, then expand each fraction as a series noting its radius of convergence.  $4-x=2(1-x)^2-2(2-x)(1-x)+3(2-x)$ should help with the partial fraction...